# Limit the number of ElasticSearch outputs

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have this code; that can successfully do an ElasticSearch.

```
es = Elasticsearch()
index_name = 'db'
query_param = Q('bool', must = [Q('match_phrase', doc_text='electronic')])
search = Search(using=es, index="db").query(query_param)
result = search.execute()
```

The problem; when i print result, it only prints the top 10 hits (even though I know there are >500,000 entries in the db).

I've read the solution should be to use the 'size' parameter/or from and size. However, no matter where I insert 'size':50 into this code, or from and size parameters, I still can't change the number of outputs returned.

Could someone show me where in the code I can change the number of outputs returned? I want to limit the number based on the number of hits, not by kb or time or anything like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out the answer is really simple, posting it here in case it helps anyone else (see the line where I've added in [0:50]).

```
    es = Elasticsearch()
    index_name = 'db'
    query_param = Q('bool', must = [Q('match_phrase', doc_text='electronic')])
    search = Search(using=es, index="db").query(query_param)[0:50]
    result = search.execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [Elasticsearch python API](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search), you have `from_` and `size` parameters to perform your request.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have found that, my problem is not knowing where specifically I put those parameters? For example: `search = Search(using=es, index="db",from_ = 0, size = 50).query(q)` doesn't work; I've been trying to move the from_ and size parameters around, and changing them from '=' to ':' and between strings and integers; but I can't seem to get it to work, so if someone could show me specifically where they should go/in what format (i.e. = or :, integer or string), I would appreciate it.

Comment: You are not using the same API, my link is an other, and you can use pagination with this one. Try it, it's very simple : just init ES like this : `es = Elasticsearch(host="localhost", port=9200)` and then you can perform your query : `res = es.search("db", body=json.dumps(data), from_=5, size=20)` where data is an Elasticsearch query as json format. All explications at the [beginning](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did try that but it didn't work for me (i got errors), unfortunately i'm not enough of an elasticsearch expert to understand the in's and out's yet, so I've found a work-around that I've posted as an answer in case it helps anyone else. Thanks again.